# Build IPA with MobileIron SDK failed

Tags: ios, sdk

When I want to build the IPA with the MobileIron SDK I get the following error:

…/Release-iphoneos/Mobile.app/Info.plist does not exist or is not a regular file.

The paths in Xcode are all set correctly

Without the MobileIron SDK it works.

Can someone please help me?

Best Regards

I have checked the references to the Info.plist. Also removed and added them again, but still get the error.